# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Rx' in 'C:\MAMP\htdocs\AngularFrontEnd\src\app'

Tags: angular

I recently started tinkering with Angular and watching videos, but upon attempting to follow a certain tutorial, I got hit with this error `"Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Rx' in 'C:\MAMP\htdocs\AngularFrontEnd\src\app'"`. The error is in this file:

quote.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class QuoteService {
    constructor(private http: Http){

    }
    getQuotes() {
        return this.http.get('http://onyx.space/api/quotes')
        .map(
            (response: Response) => {
                return response.json().quotes;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Sadly, since I'm new to this, I'm not sure what troubleshooting steps to take.

Comment: Start by removing that import from the service. If this is your entire service, you likely don't need it. While you are at it, stop using `Http`, and move to [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/guide/http). `Http` is deprecated, and will go away soon.

Comment: A lot of videos and tutorials are outdated. It's wise to not look at stuff made more than a year ago. Preferably follow the tutorials on the official [angular](https://angular.io) site

Comment: You shouldn't import from 'rxjs' or 'rxjs/Rx' since either import will import the whole of rxjs which will dramatically increase the size of your bundle. But if you are using a new version of Rxjs, you don't need to do that anymore. Just import the necessary operators as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `import 'rxjs/Rx';` and try to read more about rxjs from [angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/observables)